# How can I check in my jquery if the return value from php is 'true' or 'false'?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

On the php site I have a select query and a statement at the end:

```
if ($stmt->num_rows >=1) {
        // A user with this email address already exists
        echo "false";
    }
    else{
        echo "true";
    }
```

Now in my jquery code, based on the value returned, I want to display alert or not. So I'm doing ajax call:

```
(...)
dataType:'text',
                    success: function(ans)
                    {
                        var data = ans;
                        if (ans ==='true'){

                            alert("here");
                        }
                        else{

                          alert("else");
                        }

                }});
(...)
```

And even though my php script prints out true, I never see the alert "here" in my jquery. Why?

Comment: Have you checked what else the script is outputting? (a string with spaces or new lines in it is different to one without). What does `alert(ans.length)` say? What does `alert("--" + ans + "--");` say?

Comment: Does your php output anything else?  What exactly are you getting back?  In your JS code, instead of if/else, put `alert(ans);` - and see what you get.

Comment: What your ```alert(ans)``` printing?

Comment: I put `console.log(ans)` and I'm getting just `true`, I'm not sure what might be wrong here

Comment: however, `console.log(ans.length);` returns... 6 :O

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is extra whitespace in the php output. You can resolve this by trimming that whitespace

Change:

```
 var data = ans;
```

To

```
 var data = $.trim(ans);
```

A more practical solution is to always use json